# Adding printer to print Server via powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line

Im wanting to add a printer and its port to the print server only if either that printer name and printer port isn't already taken.

I have this so far

```
   $prnt = Import-Csv C:\scripts\printer.csv

   foreach ($printer in $prnt) {
   $var = Get-Printer

   If (($var.name -contains $printer.Printername) -and ($var.portname -contains 
   $printer.IPAddress))
   {
    Write-Host "$printer exist!" -ForegroundColor Blue
   }
   else
   {
    Add-PrinterPort -ComputerName Printsrv01 -Name $printer.IPAddress - 
    PrinterHostAddress $printer.IPAddress
    Add-Printer -ComputerName Printsrv01 -Name $printer.Printername - 
    DriverName $printer.Driver -PortName $printer.IPAddress -Location 
    $printer.Location
   }
   }
```

Problem is mainly with my 'if' statement. It catches the printer name but not the portnumber/ip. (The portnumber is the ip). And I also think my if statement is comparing the whole array of values from the csv file, and not just the specific value in the array like I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Csv file is setup like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Q6w.png)

Comment: looks fine...except that the -and should be an or i think because the port may be added as a different name....also move the `$var = get-printer` outside the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$prnt = Import-Csv C:\scripts\printer.csv
$printers = (Get-Printer).Name
$ports = (Get-PrinterPort).PrinterHostAddress
foreach ($printer in $prnt)
{
    If (($printers -contains $printer.Printername) -or ($ports -contains $printer.IPAddress))
    {
        Write-Host "$printer exist!" -ForegroundColor Blue
    }
    else
    {
        Add-PrinterPort -ComputerName Printsrv01 -Name $printer.IPAddress -PrinterHostAddress $printer.IPAddress
        Add-Printer -ComputerName Printsrv01 -Name $printer.Printername -DriverName $printer.Driver -PortName $printer.IPAddress -Location $printer.Location
    }
}
```